# VBA to Create Dynamic Named Ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to create named ranges of cells named after the top left cell in each range. This shows what I mean:
[image]

Here, I want to have 4 named ranges (Names A, Names B, Names C, Names D) so I can reference them. Is there a way to have excel look for any cell in Column B that starts with "Names" and have it cut off the range when it hits the next cell that starts with "Names"? I apologize if this is not possible, I am still new to excel and not sure if this is doable. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a quick thrown together script to provide the idea of how to approach this. By no means is it pretty, but does show the steps. This can be a lot more complexly written, ie to work with all cells, not start after the first instance of names (See Range("B3") for start, and Range("B4") for starting the looping of cells)

```
Sub DefineRanges()
    Dim rngStart As Range
    Set rngStart = Range("B3")
    Dim NamedRangeCount As Integer
    NamedRangeCount = 0
    Dim NameRangeName As String
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    For Each cell In Range("B4:B18")
        If LCase(Left(cell.Value, 5)) = "names" Then
            NameRangeName = "Name_" & NamedRangeCount
            ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=NameRangeName, RefersToLocal:=Range(rngStart.Address & ":D" & cell.Row - 1)
            Set rngStart = Range("B" & cell.Row)
            NamedRangeCount = NamedRangeCount + 1
        End If
        LastRow = cell.Row
    Next
    NameRangeName = "Name_" & NamedRangeCount
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=NameRangeName, RefersToLocal:=Range(rngStart.Address & ":D" & LastRow)
End Sub
```

Comment: That worked perfectly as I wanted it to! Thank you for making it simple, I can easily follow what you did and understand it better now. I appreciate your help very much.